# Angular 4 ng serve --prod vs ng serve

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack, angular-cli

Shortly, I have an app which is 4.6MB on ng serve.

When I do:

> ng serve --prod

I get 1MB file size.

However, the --prod somehow make my entire application break.

My whole services (promises based) which send a request to the server are no longer working.

The bizzar thing is that simply **ng serve** works perfectly fine **AND** certain parts of **ng serve --prod** works fine as well, as long as there is no server request.

I do not post any code since **ng serve** version works ok.

The main question is:

Why do I get hat kind of behavior?

Moreover, at some point, the app based on **ng serve --prod** suddenly fully worked out of nowhere and then after I restarted the app, once again, a broken app.

**EDIT:** **more EXPLICIT details:**

I am using Fiddler to make sure all of the details are correct:

[image: Fiddler pic]

As you can see, details are ok.

Now for the code which responsible to simulate that request on the client side:

```
    login(uName: string, pw: string, type: number): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        if (type === 1) {
            const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });
            const body = JSON.stringify({ username: uName, password: pw });
            this.http.post(this.loginUrl, body, options)
                .toPromise()
                .then(response => {
                    resolve(response);
                })
                .catch(this.handleError);
        } else if (type === 2 || type === 3) {
            this.http.post(this.loginUrl, { username: uName, token: pw })
                .toPromise()
                .then(response => {
                    resolve(response);
                })
                .catch(this.handleError);
        }
    });
}
```

Now notice how everything works perfect when I use **ng serve** only (Network Tab):

[image: ng serve]

As you can see, I am already logged in and I do get a response.

Now,

The moment I do

> ng serve --prod

Suddenly the same login request with the same details no longer works:

[image: ng serve --prod]

This is super bizzar.

All of my methods which are responsible for server requests are all the same.

**"Bad Request"** with some error code that comes from the server itself (my own server code like "email not filled" which is also bizzar since I do send the correct parameters)

Comment: Did you compare the webpack config files for production and development?

Comment: I knew I am forgetting something. @AmanArora - I am using Angular-CLI

Comment: What are the errors that you get when navigating/retrieving data?

Comment: @DeborahK Hi Deborah, I've just edited my post with more info.

Comment: you should use rxjs observables instead of promise to handle http response, by default http request returns an observable.

Answer (score 8):

when you did `ng serve --prod` angular cli make a production build with tree shaking and AOT (Ahead Of Time) compilation and generate less code compare to normal build. You also run in local what it will be like in prod mode

Means it tree shake all your components and added which ever actually used in your code, not all. That's why you see the `vendor.js` is really small when you did `ng serve --prod`

disadvantage is it is less debuggable as its compiled and minified code

you can read in detail in the cli documentation which build is doing what.

Comment: Hi thx for your response. I know that already. I want this behaviour. However, I can not really understand why the Tree shaking would make my app crash on server requests. **EDIT: all of my server requests are inside a 'service' folder with services files (.ts extensions). The services folder is inside src/app while the I have the newest angular-cli. It sounds as if it won't include my services, but I do get error codes from the server.

Comment: hmm, both the build process are different, in our application also same thing happens. some of the code shows error in prod/aot build. so we fix them before comit code.

Answer (score 4):

`--prod` is the option of build, default is debug mode

Let's see an example why application breaks, see we have code like this:

```
<div (click)="toshow = !toShow">Toggle</div>
```

imagine, toshow is not defined on the component or by mistake we did a typo say `toShow` to `toshow`.

In this case `ng build` and `ng serve` will work but `ng build --prod` and `ng serve --prod` will give error

Comment: I am not getting errors after ng serve --prod. I am getting errors when navigating into components which use my services files (each service has its own get/post methods via promises)

Answer (score 1):

We also faced similar issue and fixed by following these guidelines. The issue is AOT do not support some features which JIT supports. Please check this link. hopefully it will help you.

https://github.com/rangle/angular-2-aot-sandbox

[Angular DOC About AOT Restrictions](https://angular.io/guide/metadata#metadata-restrictions)